# Storing Firebase data as an array, and then use this array to create a pie chart

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase

I'm getting data from Firebase, and then storing it inside arrays.  I then try to use these arrays with the iOS Charts library.  However, I get the following errors:

Cannot assign value of type 'charts2Model' to type 'Double'
Cannot assign value of type 'chartsModel' to type 'String?'

The two functions are as per below:

//My models are as follows:

```
    class chartsModel {

var FullName: String?

init(FullName: String?){
    self.FullName = FullName

}
    }
```

//and:

```
    class charts2Model {

var Opened: Double?

init(Opened: Double?){
    self.Opened = Opened
}
    }
```

// I have declared the arrays as follows:

```
    var chartArray = [chartsModel]()
    var chartArray2 = [charts2Model]()
```

// The first function gets the data from Firebase and stores the values in their respective arrays.

```
func chartDataFromFB(){

    databaseReference = Database.database().reference()


    let refChallenges = Database.database().reference(withPath: "Users")

    refChallenges.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {  (snapshot) in

        //if the reference have some values
        if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {

            chartArray.removeAll()

            //iterating through all the values
            for Challenges in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                //getting values
                let challengeObject = Challenges.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                let FirstName  = challengeObject?["FirstName"]
                let Opened  = challengeObject?["Opened"]

                let chartsObject = chartsModel(FullName: FirstName as! String?)

                chartArray.append(chartsObject)

                let chartsObject2 = charts2Model(Opened: Opened as! Double?)

                chartArray2.append(chartsObject2)

            }

        }

    })

}
```

// The second function is partial, and what I'm trying to use for generating the pie chart:

```
func makeChart(){

    let chart = PieChartView(frame: self.view.frame)


    var entries = [PieChartDataEntry]()
    for (index, value) in chartArray2.enumerated() {
        let entry = PieChartDataEntry()
        entry.y = value
        entry.label = chartArray[index]
        entries.append( entry)
      }
    }
```

I get the errors at the following lines:

```
    entry.y = value
    entry.label = chartArray[index]
```

I'm hoping to be able to get rid of the two errors and get my chart working.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the way is to map chartArray and chartArray2 to different types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your chartArray and chartArray2 contains charModel and chart2Model elements.

You need to access their attribute FullName and Opened.

So, change this:

```
 entry.y = value
 entry.label = chartArray[index]
```

to this:

```
 entry.y = value.Opened!
 entry.label = chartArray[index].FullName!
```

> ***Some Advices***:
>
> 1. Class name usually are capitalized: chartModel -> ChartModel, it's not mandatory, but is a good practice
> 2. Class attribute name are camelCase: FullName -> fullName, as above
> 3. Don't cast to optional: as! String? -> as! String
> 4. A good practice is always check optionals:
>      Ex:
>       entry.y = value.Opened! 
>      should be
>         
>           `if let v = value.Opened{
>             entry.y = v
>           }`
>       
>      And so for all other optionals
> 5. It's a good practice to incapsulate class attribute and use a computed property to access them or get/set functions